# IsRefreshing not found on model. Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need to add the ability to update user data using RefreshView, but I get an error message. This page also displays the news that I receive using the method and it turns out to refresh them successfully

Here is my page where UserData should be updated:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:models="clr-namespace:EcoTracker.Models"
         x:Class="EcoTracker.Views.MainPage"
         x:DataType="models:UserData">

<ContentPage.Title>
    Новостная лента
</ContentPage.Title>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <RefreshView x:Name="refreshView" RefreshColor="#7bb040" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label FontSize="30" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="Eco" TextColor="#009444" />
                                <Span Text="Tracker" TextColor="#7bb040" />
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                    <Label Text="" FontSize="24" TextColor="#009444" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="Привет," FontSize="24" TextColor="#81b745" />
                                <Span Text="" FontSize="24" TextColor="#009444" />
                                <Span Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="24" TextColor="#009444" />
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
```

This is what my refresh method looks like:

```
public ObservableCollection<NewsItem> NewsItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<NewsItem>();
private UserData _user;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadNewsAsync();
    LoadUserData();
    BindingContext = this;
}

private bool _isRefreshing;
public bool IsRefreshing
{
    get { return _isRefreshing; }
    set
    {
        if (_isRefreshing != value)
        {
            _isRefreshing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
        }
    }
}

private void LoadUserData()
{
    _user = UserDataHolder.GetUserData();
    if (_user != null)
    {
        BindingContext = null;
        BindingContext = _user;
    }
}

public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => await RefreshDataAsync());

private async Task RefreshDataAsync()
{
    IsRefreshing = true;

    await LoadNewsAsync();
    LoadUserData();

    IsRefreshing = false;
}
```

I get an error: XFC0045 Binding:

> Property "IsRefreshing" not found on "EcoTracker.Models.UserData".

Comment: in the code behind, you are doing `BindingContext = this;`, but in the XAML you are doing `x:DataType="models:UserData"`.  Those two things need to match

Answer (score 0):

> Property "IsRefreshing" not found on "EcoTracker.Models.UserData".

Just as Jason mentioned, in `MainPage.xaml`, you set the `x:DataType="models:UserData"` for your page, but you also set the `BindingContext = this;` for it. This can lead to problems.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadNewsAsync();
    LoadUserData();
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

So, you can try to remove the following code from `MainPage.xaml`:

```
    x:DataType="models:UserData"
```

Besides, there are some other problems for your code, if you set `_user` for the `BindingContext` for your page after loading the data, then you cannot trigger command `RefreshCommand` again.

```
  if (_user != null)
    {
        BindingContext = null;
        BindingContext = _user;
    }
```

As a summary, to make your code look more logical and clearer, I recommend that you use [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) to achieve this.

You can refer to the following code:

1.create a view model `TestViewModel.cs` and add necessary code to it.

```
public class TestViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<NewsItem> NewsItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<NewsItem>();

    //private UserData _user;
    public UserData _user { get; set; }

    private bool _isRefreshing;
    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get { return _isRefreshing; }
        set
        {
            if (_isRefreshing != value)
            {
                _isRefreshing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
            }
        }
    }

    public TestViewModel() {
        _user = new UserData();

        LoadUserData("initial name");
    }

    private void LoadUserData(string name)
    {
        // _user = UserDataHolder.GetUserData();

        _user.Name = name;  // add fake date here

    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => await RefreshDataAsync());

    private async Task RefreshDataAsync()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;

        //await LoadNewsAsync();

        LoadUserData("upated name ");

        IsRefreshing = false;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

2.implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `UserData.cs`.
If we change the value of property `Name`, the UI will refresh itself.

```
public class UserData: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
            get { return _name; }
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

3.Usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:refreshviewdemo="clr-namespace:RefreshViewDemo"
             x:Class="RefreshViewDemo.MyTestPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <refreshviewdemo:TestViewModel></refreshviewdemo:TestViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RefreshView x:Name="refreshView" RefreshColor="#7bb040" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label FontSize="30" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="Eco" TextColor="#009444" />
                                    <Span Text="Tracker" TextColor="#7bb040" />
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Text="" FontSize="24" TextColor="#009444" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="Привет," FontSize="24" TextColor="#81b745" />
                                    <Span Text="" FontSize="24" TextColor="#009444" />
                                    <Span Text="{Binding _user.Name}" FontSize="24" TextColor="#009444" />
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </RefreshView>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

We should define `_user`  in view model as follows:

```
  public UserData _user { get; set; }
```

And bind the data like this:

```
   <Span Text="{Binding _user.Name}" FontSize="24" TextColor="#009444" />
```

Comment: Hi  @Данил Грицан, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.